# Using Ember.js in Existing Application

Tags: ember.js

I've done some example apps in Ember, and now I'm ready for using it in existing application. Its traditional web application (request-response, full reload and some ajax loaded content, no rest/api things)
So lets assume I've few page (urls) like

```
 1  abc.com/home.php
 2. abc.com/support.php ,
 3. abc.com/support.php?call=meeting
and so on..
```

so is it possible to use just one url with ember app and rest leave as such untill its ready?

PS: I did try for support.php as this.route("support",{path:"/support.php"}) and have SupportController and support.hbs template but its not working. I'm not sure how to put it in jsfiddle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Include your ember app only on the page that needs it, so only on `abc.com/support.php`

As far as ember can see, when you go to `abc.com/support.php` you are on the index page (of the ember app), and you will need to use the index.hbs tempate.